# Outlook Add-In Where to save configuration, C#

Tags: deployment, outlook, outlook-addin

I am developing a add-in for outlook using VS2008, C#.

I am trying to figure out a way to allow user to specify some settings during the installation and use them in the add-in.

seeking ways I don't have to write use registry.

thanks in advance~

Answer (score 3):

Thanks,

I actually decided to read the outlook addins registry for the installed location and have configuration file copied there during installation. so far it works fine :)

Comment: Don't forget about UAC problems on vista!

Answer (score 1):

app.config, and make sure that it's copied to dll directory?

Answer (score 1):

Its an Addin, so how exactly is

> app.config, and make sure that it's
>   copied to dll directory?

going to help?

Basically you would need to create a file called Outlook.exe.config and put it in the Office12 folder with Outlook.exe (c:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office12)

If you do this it will get loaded, the only potential issue is that it is also available to any other addins that are loaded into the outlook.exe process.
A better idea is just as the OP suggested an use an arbitary config file copied to the targetdir and read it from there.